# Best way to access and close a postgres database using python dataset

Tags: python, postgresql, dataset

```
import dataset    
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

db = dataset.connect(path_database, engine_kwargs={'poolclass': NullPool})

table_f1 = db['name_table']
# Do operations on table_f1

db.commit()
db.executable.close()
```

I use this code to access a postgres database and sometimes write to it. Finally, I close it. Is the above code the best way to access and close it? Alternatively, is the code below better?

```
import dataset    
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

with dataset.connect(path_database, engine_kwargs={'poolclass': NullPool}) as db:
    table_f1 = db['name_table']
    # Do operations on table_f1

    db.commit()
```

In particular, I want to make 100% sure that there is no connection to the postgres database once this piece of code is done. Which is the better way to achieve it? option 1 or option 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For now, the main issue is that the context manager used in Option 2 (*with statement*) doesn't handle the connection, only the [transaction](https://github.com/pudo/dataset/blob/master/dataset/persistence/database.py#L123) (commit/rollback at the end of the block).

(This question is already reported to the [Github repo](https://github.com/pudo/dataset/issues/211), maybe the behavior will change ?)

So you should replace `db.commit()` by `db.executable.close()` in Option 2:

```
import dataset    
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

with dataset.connect(path_database, engine_kwargs={'poolclass': NullPool}) as db:
    table_f1 = db['name_table']
    print(db.local.conn.closed) # >>>False

    # Do operations on table_f1
    # end of the context manager, trying to commit 

db.executable.close()
print(db.local.conn.closed) # >>>True
```

Now connection is closed :

```
# db['name_table'].all() ==> throws an error due to closed connection
```

BUT... you can still create new tables in the database (because of Metadata ?) :

```
# db['new_table'] ==> enough to add a new table
```

So you may want to destroy everything to prevent this (`db = None`, or `db.metadata = None`)

---

This last behavior happens in SQLAlchemy too:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

engine = create_engine('postgresql:///datatest', poolclass=NullPool) 

connection = engine.connect()
meta = MetaData(engine)
t1 = Table('Table_1', meta,
           Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
           Column('name',String))
t1.create()
connection.close()

t2 = Table('Table_2', meta,
           Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
           Column('name',String))
t2.create()
# table_2 is created in database
```

EDIT:

(thanks to Ilja Everilä's comment, and a focus on [the doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#engine-disposal))

Better call `meta = MetaData(connection)` in order to close the connection at the engine disposal, this will raise an error in the above example, connection IS closed.

Comment: `t1.create()` is unrelated to the created connection in your SQLA example. You pass the engine as bind to `MetaData`, which it uses directly. The latter `t2.create()` as well. Try replacing `MetaData(engine)` with `MetaData(connection)` and observe the results.