# Checking if connection to database exists before opening a new one in python

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, dataset

```
import dataset

class db(object):
    _db_connection = None
    _db_cur = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._db_connection = dataset.connect(path_to_database)

    def __del__(self):
        self._db_connection.executable.close()
```

In the code above, I create a class to connect to an existing database on AWS. Is there a way I can check if connection is already open and if so, return existing connection rather than open a new connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a descriptor for that:

```
class DBConn(object):
    conn = None

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        if self.conn is None or self.conn.closed():
            # Since this is a class attribute, it is shared by all instances
            self.conn = dataset.connect(path_to_database)
        return self.conn

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        self.conn.executable.close()
        self.conn = None
```

And then just use it as a property:

```
class DB(object):
    connection = DBConn()

db = DB()
db.connection.do_something()  # Opens a new connections
other_db = DB()
other_db.connection.do_something_else()  # Reuses same connection
del db.connection  # Closes the connection
other_db.connection.another_thing()  # Reopens the connection
```

Comment: thanks @Artyer, instead of `del db.connection`, can I instead use a `with` context manager?

Comment: @user308827 Sure, if the connection is a context manager object.

Comment: thanks, also what is `owner` in the `__get__` method?

Comment: @user308827 See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18038707/5754656 for a longer write up on descriptors, but basically, `instance` is the object accessing the property, and `owner` is the class. `instance` is not set if you call `DB.connection` instead of `DB().connection`, which I made return the descriptor itself, which is standard behaviour.

Comment: thanks, what does `if instance is None: return self` do?

Comment: @user308827 `instance` is `None` when you try and access it on the class (So, `DB.connection` instead of `db = DB(); db.connection`). In that case, return the descriptor (The object with the `__get__` and `__set__` methods, rather than a database connection), which makes it less confusing for debugging mostly, and prevents accidentally making connections.

Answer (score 2):

It's called Singleton pattern take a look at: 
http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html

```
class OnlyOne(object):
    class __OnlyOne:
        def __init__(self):
            self.val = None
        def __str__(self):
            return `self` + self.val
    instance = None
    def __new__(cls): # __new__ always a classmethod
        if not OnlyOne.instance:
            OnlyOne.instance = OnlyOne.__OnlyOne()
        return OnlyOne.instance
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, name)
    def __setattr__(self, name):
        return setattr(self.instance, name)
```

Answer (score 1):

on connect, you may get an exception if the driver can't connect

so you need to wrap your connect call into a

```
class db(object):
    _db_connection = None
    _db_cur = None

    def __init__(self):
       try:
           self._db_connection = dataset.connect(path_to_database)
       except WhateverExceptionYourDBDriverThrowsOnError:
           pass

    def __del__(self):
        if self._db_connection:
            self._db_connection.executable.close()
```

You didn't say what driver, what DB you use, so this is generic code. You need to replace the Exception type with the proper one thrown by your driver.

Comment: thanks @MrE, I am slightly confused, can you integrate your answer into the code I have provided? In particular, does the check for `if self._db_connection` go into the `_init_` function?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.local.conn.closed # return True or False
```

I use it in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679641/best-way-to-access-and-close-a-postgres-database-using-python-dataset/44742067#44742067)

Comment: sorry i didn't check who was asking :) thanks to you, i appreciated you open the bounty again

Comment: not a problem, thanks again for the answer here as well as the bounty answer